# "Save as" dialog is not shown in IE11 when page is loaded as "sandbox"

Tags: internet-explorer-11, sandbox, content-security-policy

I try to download file on click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a onclick="handler()">Click Here</a>
<iframe id="mmain" name="mmain" height="400" width="400"></iframe>
<script>
function handler() {
document.getElementById("mmain").src = "http://localhost:8083/myapp/test_content";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `test_content` is generated with the following headers:

```
 response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
 response.setHeader("X-Content-Security-Policy", "sandbox;");
```

However, Save As dialog is not shown in IE11 (works OK in Chrome and Firefox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Remove "sandbox" header.
2. Use `<a href="http://localhost:8083/myapp/test_content" target="mmain">Click Here</a>` instead of javascript (`target` doesn't have to be frame name, it can be, for example, `_self`).